# Replace integer(0) in the cells of a dataframe containing lists

Tags: r, list, csv, dataframe

I need to export a dataframe from R in CSV format, with some cells having integer(0) values, and other are lists (stored in the dataframe using `df$B[k]=list(vector)`)

```
A              B                  C
Comp1          integer(0)         c(17, 15)
Comp2          integer(0)         integer(0)                                
Comp3          c(15, 14)          integer(0)  
Comp4          15                 c(12, 13, 14)
Comp5          c(16, 13, 12)      integer(0)
```

When exported in CSV with `fwrite(df, "data.csv")`, value of *column n* is shifted to *column n-1* if the value of the cell of the *column n-1* is integer(0) .

I tried :

```
df$B <- as.character(df$B)
df$B[df$B == "integer(0)"] <- "."
```

But as some cells contain lists, I cannot use `as.character` and replace "integer(0)" by Something else as it will mess with some cells (list are vectors with ',' in it which will be interpreted as tab when converted with `as.character` and exported to CSV).

Any way to work around that ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would have been nice if you had provided us the code from `dput(df)`, like suggested in the question about reproducible examples.
Anyway this is how I generated  `df`:

```
df <- data.frame(A = c("Comp1", "Comp2", "Comp3", "Comp4", "Comp5"))
for(k in 1:5){
  donors <- 16:12
  pick <- list(k1 = 0, k2 = 0, k3 = c(2, 3), k4 = 2, k5 = c(1, 4, 5))
  vector <- donors[pick[[k]]]
  df$B[k] <- list(vector)
}
```

First thing that come into my mind: is it really necessary to save lists in a data.frame? Second thing: presuambly `vector` in your example is a vector. But `vector` is the name of a function implemented in `R` (see `?vector`), so I would give your vector a different name (e.g. `vec`). 
To your question: I would not run

```
df$B <- as.character(df$B)
df$B[df$B == "integer(0)"] <- "."
```

but

```
df$B[sapply(df$B, length) == 0] <- NA
fwrite(df, "data.csv", na = ".")
```

Comment: This perfectly solve the issue, thank you very much; I didn't know about the saving option `na='.'`. Also I'll make sure to improve the description of my issues next time. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can still update your question. And if you think my answer is useful, you can upvote it in addition to the acceptance.